# 16.10 - dragging a file/folder onto another folder no longer opens the target folder

Tags: nautilus, drag-and-drop

**Ubuntu 16.10**. I just noticed a new behaviour, and I'm wondering when/why this has changed.

**before**: when dragging a file/folder onto another folder icon, the target folder used to open to display its contents, at which point you could release the original file/folder wherever you'd like.

**now**: when dragging a file/folder onto another folder icon, the target folder now just changes its icon to a partially open folder icon.

When/why did that change? Is the "before" behaviour from 16.04?"

Comment: To answer the last question: Nautilus definitely behaves like that in 16.04. I love that feature!

Comment: A few people  liked that feature, others found it annoying and despised it such as myself. I guess canonical decided to compromise.

Comment: Never notice lol! I'll have to test this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnome came to their senses & in a rare occurrence made it an option, (hidden), the default is false. Can be changed in dconf-editor or thru gsettings.

Reference for ubuntu - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-settings/+bug/1532370

From cli

`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences open-folder-on-dnd-hover true`

In new dconf-editor, click on value to pop up edit box, ect. ect.

[image]

Comment: I just tried this, and it didn't change the behavior. The pref is there. I changed it, tried dnd, and compiz crashed. Logged out/in, same behavior. Maybe they changed their minds again.

Comment: Try it from the cli

Comment: CLI same thing. Changed the setting. Quit Nautilus and restarted it. Same whether it's true or false.

Comment: Weird, plus the change should be immediate. Maybe try going into a guest session, use dconf-editor or cli & see if it works there.

Comment: Same behaviour in the Guest account.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu  (unity), or Gnome  (gnome-shell)?

Comment: I'm using Unity

Comment: Doesn't make much sense as I'm sure this works as described for 99%+ of users. Can you change any option in dconf-editor? Something to try may be to set the default for this option to true & see how that works for you. Not that hard to do but not exactly suitable to show in a comment.  If inclined post about this dconf issue in Ubuntu forums & we'll see what can be done..

Comment: I'll give that a try too. They wouldn't put the setting there if it didn't do anything. Thanks so much for staying with this! I'll keep you posted.